# How can I trace Operational Analytics in MobileFirst Platform 6.3 to determine why data is being lost?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

I'm working in a scenario where we are trying to get Operational Analytics working within an MFP 6.3 environment. There is a MobileFirst client application (hybrid, if it matters), a MFP 6.3 server, and an Operational Analytics server (the system is for dev/test only, so is lightly loaded, and no uptime/performance concerns exist).

Currently, we are seeing intermittent problems, where data sometimes appears in the Operational Analytics console on adapter invocations etc., and then for some periods (sometimes days) go past with no data showing up.

How can we trace or log the behaviour of the Operational Analytics engine? As I understand it, there is a queueing mechanism on the MFP 6.3 server (currently `wl.analytics.queue=1` and `wl.analytics.queue.size=0`) for forwarding data from the client to the OA server. Is there a way to see what messages are put or got from this queue?

This environment uses WAS ND.

Comment: Is your analytics server and worklight server on the same server?

Comment: Same physical server, yes, but they are on two different WAS application server instances.

Comment: Did you change the queue size and the number of queues? Have you restarted your server since those changes were made?

Comment: Also, would you be willing to do a packet trace on that machine? Might see what is causing the issue in a network trace.

Comment: This kind of issue is not uncommon when setting up OA. So far as I can see by default we get no log messages from the server to tell us when messages are getting into the queues, when delivery to the OA server is being attempted, or whether problems are happening with delivery. The first question here is whether we can set a trace string to get some such information?

Comment: Chevy, yep, we changed the queue and queue.size as I mentioned in the question above.

Comment: Chevy, we can try a packet trace with Wireshark. I was hoping there was a less invasive method, as this is in a running datacenter and setting that up isn't that easy. As @djna mentions, is there a trace string?

Comment: Unfortunately there is very little tracing being done for analytics on 6.3. So a wireshark is going to give us a much better idea on what is happening. Is there any consistency on what you are seeing and what you are not seeing or is it all just random?

Comment: So there seems to be some pattern now. It appears to work somewhat (although we are still missing some data, but that could be a different problem) if we map the WL Project's WAR onto the analytics server. But if we don't (just installing the analytics WAR) we don't get any data through. Is it supposed to be required to install the project WAR on the analytics instances?

Comment: You should not need to map the WL Project's WAR onto the analytics server. Make sure that you are including all the appropriate environment variables to send data. Do you have the data path set? In liberty it looks like:

    <jndiEntry jndiName="<project-name>/wl.analytics.url" value="http://localhost:10080/worklight-analytics-service/data"/>

Comment: Chevy, yep, we have that set. The problem seems to have disappeared now. We still don't really have any way to tell why, which is a bit of a shame, but since we can't recreate, I think we can consider this closed.

Comment: That is good to hear that it works now. Sorry we could not come to a solution. Thanks for letting us know your system is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

From an IBM engineer:

> IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 does not provide traceability options in
>   the MFP Operational Analytics component. This was greatly improved in
>   MFP 7.0 in the log output from the various analytics components,
>   including the queues and sender embedded in MFP server and the
>   receiver, processors, and storage in the Analytics server, and more is
>   planned for the future.

If deemed required in MFP 6.3 consider opening a PMR (support ticket). Or upgrade to MFP 7.0 if possible.

Comment: Can you list out the logging settings for 7.0? This would be a useful place to reference that.

Comment: CORRECTION: in 7.0, the precise trace strings are `com.worklight.analytics.*=all:com.ibm.mbaas.analytics.*=all`.