# MobileFirst 7.0 Operational Analytics - No Data loaded

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

I configured the Operational analytics for the MobileFirst 7.0

Configured the JDNI as per the IBM document and created client side log profile in Admin Operation Console. But it always shows 0 data. Not load any client logs / server logs.

Log receiver adapter has been built and deployed in the operation console. Client has the method to push the logs to server via WL.Logger.send(). I see the client log console and logcat, the logs has been pushed to server. In server log also, i see the invoke success log for logReceiverAdapter call.

In Operation Analytics console JNDI, the Queue and Size has been set to 1.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I trace Operational Analytics in MobileFirst Platform 6.3 to determine why data is being lost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948988/how-can-i-trace-operational-analytics-in-mobilefirst-platform-6-3-to-determine-w)

Comment: Andrew, I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: What server are you using? Are you starting any sessions i.e. connecting to the server in any way with your client?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Updated my question to explain its not a duplicate. @Chevy - Yes the client connects to server and send the logs via logReceiverAdapter by calling WL.Logger.send(). And in MobileFirst by default the operation analytics will be enabled for all the applications / Project RunTime.

Comment: And what do you see in the messages.log file in the server?

Comment: What server are you using? Are you setting the  JNDI entry: <jndiEntry jndiName="AdapterTest/wl.analytics.url" value="http://localhost:10080/analytics-service/data"/>? IS this over HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Also, do you know what version of MobileFirst platform you are running? If you are running your android device on kitkat could you open the javascript console through chrome debugger? If you are unsure how to do that, start your app, open chrome, navigate to chrome://inspect, then choose your app.

Comment: The JNDI entry for analytics URL is via HTTPS. MobileFirst Platform version is same on Server and Client. Its 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731.

Comment: My MFPF7.0 server and WAS instance are behind a firewall in a Private VLAN. So created JNDI property in Java Virtual Machine property on both the WAS01 and WAS02 instances with the https://was01host:port/analytics-service/data  over https and also set the admin username/password of the same in JNDI respectively.

Comment: Hi Chevy / Idan, I created a PMR for this. Its working fine in a single server installation. But having issues with cluster environment WAS ND full profile.  PMR Escalated to L3 support and CORD Team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was identified to be a defect in the product and will be resolved as part of APAR #PI42509 WHEN USING SSL ON WEBSPHERE THE ANALYTICS DATA IS NOT RECEIVED BY THE ANALYTICS SERVER BECAUSE OF THE SSL CONFIGURATION USED

There is no local workaround.
Continue to follow up on the issue in the PMR (support ticket) you have opened.